# Using flex to display cards on mobile

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have a website that has cards that look like this

[image]

The html and css look something like this

```
     <div class="resource-card-container">
         <div class="resource-card">
            <h3> Informal Waste Workers Contribution Bangalore </h3>
            <div class="resource-card-summary">
             he paper analyses the demographic profile of these waste-pickers..
            </div>
            <a class="resource-link" href="#"></span>
            </a>
         </div>

        //other cards

   </div>
```

//CSS

```
.resource-card-container {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 900px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


.resource-card {
  position: relative;
  width: 28%;
  border: 1px solid #e53b51;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 230px;
}
```

Now this is not going to work on a mobile device.

[image]

However on desktop I need the min-width to make the cards be wide enough.

The best behaviour on a mobile device is for the cards to be presented one by one.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flex-direction: column;` to make all the card in one column. Change 
`max-width: 400px` in `@media` according to your target mobile width.

below is updated snippet.

```css
.resource-card-container {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 900px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.resource-card {
  position: relative;
  width: 28%;
  border: 1px solid #e53b51;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 230px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media all and (max-width: 400px) {
  .resource-card-container {
    width:100%;
    min-width:100%;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .resource-card {
    width:100%
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="resource-card-container">
         <div class="resource-card">
            <h3> Informal Waste Workers Contribution Bangalore </h3>
            <div class="resource-card-summary">
             he paper analyses the demographic profile of these waste-pickers..
            </div>
            <a class="resource-link" href="#">asasaas
            </a>
         </div>
          <div class="resource-card">
            <h3> Informal Waste Workers Contribution Bangalore </h3>
            <div class="resource-card-summary">
             he paper analyses the demographic profile of these waste-pickers..
            </div>
            <a class="resource-link" href="#">asasaas
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="resource-card">
            <h3> Informal Waste Workers Contribution Bangalore </h3>
            <div class="resource-card-summary">
             he paper analyses the demographic profile of these waste-pickers..
            </div>
            <a class="resource-link" href="#">asasaas
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="resource-card">
            <h3> Informal Waste Workers Contribution Bangalore </h3>
            <div class="resource-card-summary">
             he paper analyses the demographic profile of these waste-pickers..
            </div>
            <a class="resource-link" href="#">asasaas
            </a>
         </div>
        

   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `min-width` for `.resource-card-container` and change `height` to `min-height` for `.resource-card`:

```css
.resource-card-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


.resource-card {
  position: relative;
  width: 28%;
  border: 1px solid #e53b51;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  min-height: 230px;
}
```

```html
<div class="resource-card-container">
  <div class="resource-card">
    <h3> Informal Waste Workers Contribution Bangalore </h3>
    <div class="resource-card-summary">
      he paper analyses the demographic profile of these waste-pickers..
    </div>
    <a class="resource-link" href="#"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="resource-card">
    <h3> Informal Waste Workers Contribution Bangalore </h3>
    <div class="resource-card-summary">
      he paper analyses the demographic profile of these waste-pickers..
    </div>
    <a class="resource-link" href="#"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="resource-card">
    <h3> Informal Waste Workers Contribution Bangalore </h3>
    <div class="resource-card-summary">
      he paper analyses the demographic profile of these waste-pickers..
    </div>
    <a class="resource-link" href="#"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
    <div class="resource-card">
    <h3> Informal Waste Workers Contribution Bangalore </h3>
    <div class="resource-card-summary">
      he paper analyses the demographic profile of these waste-pickers..
    </div>
    <a class="resource-link" href="#"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```